# Hold/ Re-invite not working properly in conference call

Tags: android, pjsip, csip-simple

I am working on conference call using pjsip and facing problem in hold/re-invite call.

First of all, 
I am login with user "A" using my app and another user "B","C" are registered in another softphone. Now I call to user "B" and "C" from "A" and conference create successfully.

Then User "A" hold call and call was put on hold for last added call (In this case "C" was last added user) Every time, last added user is put on hold  instead of the owner of the conference

Below is my code for hold/ re-invite

```
if (service != null) {
   if (call.getMediaStatus() == SipCallSession.MediaState.LOCAL_HOLD ||
            call.getMediaStatus() == SipCallSession.MediaState.NONE) {
            service.reinvite(call.getCallId(), true);
            Boast.makeText(this, "" + getResources().getString(R.string.on_resume), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
            service.hold(call.getCallId());
    }

 }
 Here call.getcallId() was last added call session id
```

The same secanrio is working fine for single call but facinng the problem in conference call only.

Does any one have idea how can I put owner only on hold?

Comment: the last added call has been put on hold, because you are getting callid of last added call. so you need to pass the callid of the owner which is common in the conference to put the owner in the hold.

Comment: But how can I get owner callid? I don't have owner caller info I just only have owner account id? Is it working for hold?

Comment: now if u put to hold, the hold is applied to callee c only, the problem is not holding the call for b. am i right?

Comment: no, Getting the same problem for "b" user also At a time I can put only one person on hold. Generally In conference call, hold option should be apply on owner instead of the callee (whatever added in the conference) So how can I achieve it ?

Comment: ok. if conference call is working,try to call third person. then checks, when calling third person will put hold on frst and second person or not?

Comment: I can put first person on hold

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168637/discussion-between-nandhakumar-and-himadri).

Comment: @Himadri Did you get solution?